# ¿Es posible colocar un pixel de facebook en un sitio web que no esté hecho con wordpress?

Tags: html, web, facebook, seo, google-analytics

Estoy desarollando un sitio web, pero el mismo lo estoy realizando de manera manual, sin wordpress.

Se requiere la colocación de un pixel de facebook, pero solo he visto que lo colocan en sitios web hechos con Wordpress.

He ahi que nace mi duda, puedo colocar un pixel de facebook o de google analytics en sitios web no hechos a partir de wordpress.

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], tu pub. puede terminar cerrada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede, solo que para WordPress es mas utilizado y creo que cambia un poco la dinámica pero esta función es en realidad para todos los sitios web, primero:
1 - Ve al administrador de eventos.
2 - Selecciona el píxel que quieras configurar.
3 - Haz clic en Continuar configuración del píxel.
4 - Selecciona Instalar código manualmente.
5 - Copia el código base del píxel.
(Ojo) el sitio ya debería estar en funcionamiento para realizar los pasos (o eso es lo recomendado)

Comment: Muchas gracias, si tengo en cuenta que ya tendria que haber instalado el Sitio, solo que todos los tutoriales que veo lo hacen en wordpress, ahi mi duda.